# Fill the transparent part of the drawable image a specific color

Tags: android, drawable

Currently, I have this back arrow that I'm going to use in my toolbar

[image]

What I want is to fill the middle part which a specific color which is the middle part is a transparent part.

currently what i have is this :

```
Drawable backArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back);
        backArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.aub_red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(backArrow);
```

it only changes the color of the white color part into the red color which is wrong. what I want to fill the transparent part a color not the non - transparent part.

Comment: can you post this arrow's drawable code ?

Comment: If you are displaying this in an `ImageView` later, then setting the `background` attribute for the view to your desired color (red) will yield the results you want. The opaque parts of the drawable will hide the red bg color in all places except the transparent center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this

```
 Drawable backArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back);
    backArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(backArrow);
```

for more information [click hear](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode)

Comment: got it. Thanks!

Comment: How can i do it in the button?

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(yourdrawable,getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
```

in java code, or in xml tag :

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
```